# the DataNavigateUrlFormatString escape problem in asp.net's HyperLinkField

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, escaping

I am usin the HyperLinkField in my asp.net application.

However when I use the `DateNavigateUrlFormation` I meet some problem:

This is the code :

```
<asp:hyperlinkfield datanavigateurlfields="tab_name,rowid" 
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\details.aspx?tab={0}&rowid={1}" />
```

Since sometime the `rowid` may contain some characters which has the specified meaning in the http,so in the server side I can not get the correct `rowid`.

For example,the  `rowid` of one row maybe

```
AAAAAAAXXX+BA
```

Now the generated url would be :

http://xxx/details.aspx?tab=tab_name&rowid=AAAAAAAXXX+BA

Since there is a character `+` here,I want to excape it.

I tried this:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\details.aspx?tab={0}&rowid=<%#Server.HtmlEncode({1})%>"
```

It does not work also.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle this in the [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{ 
    e.Row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Text = Server.HtmlEncode(e.Row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Text);
}
```

**Update**

[Take a look at this article](http://www.aspexception.com/resourcedepot/howto_gridviewurl.aspx)

According to that you can programatically access the hyperlink field.

```
HyperLinkField hLink = GridView1.Columns[0] as HyperLinkField;
hLink.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "details.aspx?pi=" + GridView1.PageIndex.ToString() + "&eID={0}";
```

OR I think what you need is to handle it in the *RowDataBound* event.

```
HyperLink hLink = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as HyperLink;
hLink.NavigateUrl = "test.aspx?q=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
```

Comment: But this cell is a HyperLinkField,I wonder if this will make this column as a text only.\

Comment: Thanks,I will have a try tommorrow. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a TemplateField which does support the databinding.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Link" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/details.aspx?tab={0}&rowid={1}", Convert.ToString(Eval("tab_name")), Convert.ToString(Eval("rowid"))) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This way you don't need code in CodeBehind and you don't need to access columns by index (which can easily change and thus lead to problems in the future).

Comment: Thanks, this is the most handy way and it should be the accepted answer. But you forgot to escape uri components. Pls see my answer below (can't insert code example here).

Answer (score 2):

This aswer is based on Johan van der Slikke's one. I just added Uri.EscapeDataString:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Link" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/details.aspx?tab={0}&rowid={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToString(Eval("tab_name"))), Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToString(Eval("rowid")))) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```